# redirect data from a servlet to flex page?

Tags: apache-flex, servlets

I have String datatypes in a servlet/jsp page, I have a submit button on that page, through which I want to redirect the page to flex application such that the application would print those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can append your data in the url after user click 'submit':
http://dest_flex.html?name=StackOverflow&age=20...

dest_flex.html is the host page of the .swf.
in dest_flex.html, you can use javascript get the url paramters.
in the swf, you can get the paramters from javascript in as using ExternalInterface. 
then you can dispaly the data in your flex application.

Comment: can't we hide the data from the url?

Comment: is there any other alternative?

Comment: As I known, JS can not get post parameters, so if no Server side code, you can not hide the data from the URL.  If you want to hide the data, I think you need to do some Server side coding, for example, you have a serverlet there, and get the post values, then return the modified html to the client.

Comment: can we embed flex page into jsp/html

Comment: you can modify the flex page directly